# Forcing a single cell to redraw in iGrid.NET control

Tags: .net, winforms, igrid

I'm using the `CustomDrawCellForeground` pattern to draw an image in a cell of an iGrid.NET component.

I think in the `iGrid` ActiveX component, there was a `DrawCell()` sub that I could call, but in the .NET component (https://10tec.com/winforms-grid/) I just don't find it anymore.

`Grid.Refresh` would be an overkill. It must be possible to redraw a single cell.

Could anybody please tell me how to force a cell to redraw it's foreground?

Comment: If it doesn't have an invalidation method for the cell, as an idea, maybe you can try  [`Invalidate(Rectangle)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8dtk06x2.aspx). (Just sharing an idea, I didn't tried it myself).

Comment: I tried it. It works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Invalidate(Rectangle)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8dtk06x2.aspx) method of the control to invalidate the specified rectangle of the graphics object. For example:

```
iGrid1.Invalidate(iGrid1.Cols[0].Cells[1].Bounds);
```

**Note:** The cells which you want to support custom draw for their foreground, should have `iGCustomDrawFlags.Foreground` flag for their `CustomDrawFlags` properties and also the `CustomDrawCellForeground` event should be handled and contain custom paint logic. You can find more about the control in [iGrid.NET manual](https://public.luelistan.net/manuals_docs/10Tec_iGrid.NET_4.6_Manual.pdf).

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm a bit surprised about this, I expected a dedicated method for a cell, but obviously there isn't one anymore. Perhaps the author thought that Invalidate is more modern approach to handle this.

Comment: This answer is wrong. Your code does not only invalidate a single cell as asked in the question. It works, but it invalidates all cells. Put a Debug.Write((String)i_Cell.Value); into your Custom Draw handler and you will see that the grid redraws all cells.